# DIY fix for iPhone 5 sleep-wake button issue

Tags: sleep-wake, iphone

So I bought my iPhone 5 in the US and it recently developed the sleep/wake button issue that Apple is fixing for free. Unfortunately, I am not in the US and cannot avail the free repair since the warranty isn't international (although by the serial number alone, it qualifies for a free repair).

I was wondering, can I simply replace the sleep/wake button myself given I find the required parts online? Any other remedy for this issue?

PS: Mailing to someone in the US isn't an option for me. I'm ok voiding the warranty.

Answer (score 1):

Apple's warranties are world wide however you may give up walk-in service by some authorized repair centers if they don't want to take that repair. You can arrange service in the US (since your original purchase was from the US) over the web or by phone. The mail in procedure is clearly explained at https://ssl.apple.com/support/iphone5-sleepwakebutton/

I've never heard of actual Apple stores not offering to help facilitate a US repair - even if it's helping you arrange a mail in service, but perhaps something new is up or it's a temporary delay due to parts shortage.

That being said, there's nothing preventing you from opening up the device and putting in a new sleep/wake button. For some, that "surgery" is way too hard for their skill level with tools and for others, it's a "piece of cake" since they are either trained or have the natural aptitude for repair of delicate electronics. If your device has the covered issue, it is caused by a mechanical failure and/or electrical failure of the switch itself.

Answer (score 0):

Have you actually tried the ever-hopeful trick of just playing dumb & taking it along to an Apple Store? Face to face might just get you the sympathy required for them to just do the fix anyway.

Comment: yep, they refused a repair and I was told to take it to store in the US. :/